# Does jQuery return true for :animated when the animation is a CSS transition?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, animated

Scenario:

1. Trigger a CSS transition by changing an element's class via jQuery.
2. While the CSS transition is occurring, run `if( $(elem).is(':animated') ) {…}`

Will that `if` return as true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have try it yourself, but I was curious and tested it.

http://jsfiddle.net/udedV/

The answer is no.

Using `:animated` check if the element is currently in a queue.

CSS transition do not use queue,

```
if( $(elem).is(':animated') )
```

It will alway be false if it is being animated by CSS.